# Can't define a Vector with pygame.math.Vector 2

Tags: python, pygame

I'm starting with pygame programming and I've seen vectors are useful x and y variables.

The issue is that i cant even define a vector because pycharm throws the following:

[image]

This is the body of the script:

```
import pygame as pg


class Character(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Game
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        'Initialize position'
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(1, 2)
```

Pycharm throws `"Unexpected arguments" and the following inspection Description:

```
"Reports discrepancies between declared parameters and actual arguments, as well as incorrect arguments.
```

I've been looking for the solution for hours but I can't simply make it work.
The most frustrating part is the everywhere I see they define the vectors the same way I'm trying to, and it looks so simple.

Comment: Is your code running without errors? It could be pycharm inspecting your code and finding an error that isn't really there

Comment: That was the case, i found out minutes after posting this. Thank you furas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. A [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) can be constructed either by a single argument, which is a tuple of 2 coordinates or 2 separate arguments. In fact, you discovered a bug in the IDE.